# Check if click linked in array has a submenu key value. IF true run some code ELSE run other code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object, linkItems that contains an array. I am not sure how to check the link that is clicked if it has a submenu then run some code such as don't close the menu else run close the menu?

```
                            <ul class="main-nav" onclick="{!c.onClick}">
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.linkItems}" var="item" indexVar="i">
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{!item.subMenu}">
                                            <li>
                                                <a data-menu-item-id="{!item.id}" href="JavaScript:Void(0);">{!item.label}</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <aura:iteration items="{!item.subMenu}" var="subItem" indexVar="id">
                                                    <li><a data-menu-item-id="{!subItem.id}" href="#">{!subItem.label}</a></li>
                                                </aura:iteration>
                                            </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        <aura:set attribute="else">
                                                <li><a data-menu-item-id="{!item.id}" href="">{!item.label}</a></li>
                                        </aura:set>
                                        </aura:if>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                            </ul>
```

When I console.log the var linkItems this is what is returned:

```
> Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}}
    > [[Handler]]: Object 
        [[Target]]: Array(9)
        > 0: {id: 0, label: "Home", active: false} 
        1: {id: 1, label: “About”, active: false} 
        2: {id: 2, label: “Page3”, active: false}
         3: {id: 3, label: “Page4”, active: false}
         4: {id: 4, label: “Page5”, active: false} 
        5: {id: 5, label: “Page6”, active: true} 
        6: {id: 6, label: "Page7”, active: false} 
        7: {id: 10, label: "Support Pages", subMenu: Array(3), active: false} 
        8: {id: 15, label: "More", subMenu: Array(4), active: false} length: 9 __proto__: Array(0) 
    * [[IsRevoked]]: false
```

Updated code:

```
    onClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var linkItems = component.get('v.linkItems'); //array of linkItems
        console.log('linkItems', linkItems);
        var id = event.target.dataset.menuItemId;
        console.log(id, 'id');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event.target.dataset)); //returns menuItemId
        component.set("v.selected",parseInt(id)); //sets v.selected to selected menu item id
        if (id) {

            // var linkItems = linkItems.reduce(function (acc, it) {
            //     return acc[it.id] = it, acc;
            // }, {});

            linkItems.map(function (item) {
                return item.subMenu && item.subMenu.length ? 'open' : function() {component.getSuper().navigate(id)};
            });

            //console.log(linkItems);

            //component.getSuper().navigate(id);

            // console.log('idArray', JSON.stringify(linkItems));
            // console.log(linkItems[id].id);
            // console.log('label', linkItems[id].label);
            // console.log(linkItems[id].subMenu);
            // console.log('linkItems.id', linkItems.id);
        }
    },
```

This is still not working. On click, I need to check the id of the link that was clicked then check if it has a submenu.

TIA.

Comment: Can you provide your "linkItems" array you are referencing in raw form?

Comment: @DerekGutierrez I just updated

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.filter`:

```
let itemsWithSubMenu = linkItems.filter(f => f.subMenu && f.subMenu.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i understand your problem now, assuming that `active` means clicked you have to check if active item has submenu

Also assuming that you can have more than one menu open at the same time and you want to use id of open menu in your functions

```
anySubmenuOpen = linkItems
  .map(f => {
    const submenuOpened = f.id == id && f.subMenu && f.subMenu.length > 0;
    if(submenuOpened) {
      // run code for open menu
    }
    return submenuOpened
  }).reduce((acc,curr) => acc | curr, 0)

if(!anySubmenuOpen) {
// none of the submenus is open,  close submenus
}
```

Comment: For the return statement, how would I call a function. ```var linkItems = linkItems.map(function (item) {
                return item.subMenu && item.subMenu.length ? 'open' : component.getSuper().navigate(id);
            });```

Comment: Still not working. I think onClick I need to grab the id and check if it matches the id in linkItems. I think something like this was working what I tried earlier where I could check  `// var linkItems = menuItems.reduce(function (acc, it) {
            //     return acc[it.id] = it, acc;
            // }, {});             // console.log('idArray', JSON.stringify(linkItems));
            // console.log(linkItems[id].id);
            // console.log('label', linkItems[id].label);
            // console.log(linkItems[id].subMenu);`

Comment: So say support pages was clicked, linkItems[7].id = 10 then check on click if linkItems[id].subMenu != undefined { run code }

Comment: @Fawn so lets clarify, does `active` represent clicked item?

Comment: No, I just deleted it in above example. But this line `component.set("v.selected",parseInt(id)); //sets v.selected to selected id` so that I can add a class 'active' for styling the active linkItem. This is separate  and not related to the active key value in the array above.

Comment: updated, code inside map  function will be executed for every open submenu, code outside if none of them is open

Comment: @Fawn did the new updated example worked? Or should I recreate the solution that you have mentioned it was working

Comment: Sorry to leave you hanging. This worked!!! You are the best. Thank you! Now I just need to understand how map and reduce are working... I still get confused.